# Dixon/Hall's "Fluid Mechanics and Thermodynamics of Turbomachinery" full of errors?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, turbomachinery, compressible-flow

Note: This is no homework, but self-study.

I have a thermodynamics and fluid mechanics background and am trying to work through this book in order to get better understanding of turbomachines (especially for compressible flow). The book was praised across the internet as a classic and basically one of the best turbomachinery books out there. I immediately ran into problems and I think the book has errors. I give two examples and hope you can review them. I hope you can point out mistakes on **my** side, otherwise this would heavily discourage me to further work through the book.

**First problem.** So I reviewed the topics of chapter 1 and tried to solve the end-of-chapter problems. This is literally the first problem in the book (1a is easy, 1b has the supposed error).

1a. Air flows adiabatically through a long straight horizontal duct, $0.25 \text{ m}$ diameter, at a measured mass flow rate of $40 \text{ kg/s}$. At a particular section along the duct the measured values of static temperature $T = 150 \text{ °C}$ and static pressure $p = 550 \text{ kPa}$. Determine the average velocity of the airflow and its stagnation temperature.

1b. At another station further along the duct, measurements reveal that the static temperature has dropped to $147 \text{ °C}$ as a consequence of wall friction. Determine the average velocity and the static pressure of the airflow at this station. Also determine the change in entropy per unit of mass flow between the two stations. For air assume that $R = 287 \text{ J/kg/K}$ and $\gamma = 1.4$.

Solutions.
1a is simple: $v = \frac{\dot{m}}{\rho\,A} = \frac{\dot{m}\,R\,T}{p\,A} =  179.93 \text{ m/s}$ and
$T_0 = T + \frac{v^2}{2\,\frac{\gamma\,R}{\gamma - 1}} = 439.26 \text{ K}$
which matches the book solution. But now for 1b:
$h_{01} = h_{02} = \frac{\gamma\,R}{\gamma - 1}\,T_1 + \frac{v_1^2}{2} = \frac{\gamma\,R}{\gamma - 1}\,T_2 + \frac{v_2^2}{2}$ gives $v_2 = \sqrt{2\,\left(h_{01} - \frac{\gamma\,R}{\gamma - 1}\,T_2\right)} = 195.96 \text{ m/s}$ (not even given in the book solution, even though asked), and then $p_2 = \frac{\dot{m}}{v_2\,A}\,R\,T_2 = 501.42 \text{ kPa}$ (this also matches the book solution). Buut now for the entropy we should have, since we are treating this as a perfect gas, $$ \Delta s = \frac{\gamma\,R}{\gamma - 1} \, \ln{\frac{T_2}{T_1}} - R\,\ln{\frac{p_2}{p_1}} \hspace{1cm}\text{ (also given as Eq. (1.31) in the book})$$

But this gives $\Delta s = 19.39 \text{ kJ/(kg K)}$, while the book solution gives $39.24 \text{ kJ/(kg K)}$.

This I miss anything or does the book present a false solution right from the first problem?

**Second problem.**

This leads to problems in the end-of-chapter problems, but really appears to be a big typo in an important equation. I found it right in chapter two after turning a few pages from the first problem. On page 47 (7th edition) it says:
For a compressor, the isentropic efficiency is defined in Chapter 1 and can be written as
$$ \text{Eq. (2.10a)} \hspace{1cm} \eta_C = \frac{\Delta h_{0s}}{\Delta h_0} = \frac{((p_{02}/p_{01})^{\gamma / (\gamma -1)} -1)}{\Delta T_0 / T_{01}} $$.

Now ... apparently the exponent is switched around, correct (in my opinion) is
$$ (p_{02}/p_{01})^{(\gamma -1) / \gamma} $$ from the isentropic change of state relations.

I would greatly appreciate your opinion on these two examples. I can't really work through a book when I must assume errors in the text. These I just found at first glance and in the first problems I tried, so this is really discouraging. Hope the errors are on my side!

Comment: Is there a later edition? if so are the errors the same or have they been corrected?

Comment: To my best knowledge, this is the most recent edition. But if true, then these errors are of very basic nature and this is already the 7th edition. For being such a praised book, this should have been noticed by someone reviewing it earlier ... right?

Comment: So who would you blame? the author? All the other readers for not saying anything? What about the editor for not publishing corrections that they received?

Comment: I dont know much about such publishing processes, so I am not in the position to blame anyone here. But can you follow my reasoning and do you also come to the conclusion that these are errors in the book, rather than on my side?

Comment: The errata I have for the 7th edition, ch1, only lists Chapter 1
Page 12, Eq. (1.26b) Tds = dh−νdp
Page 15 Cv =(dut/dt)v

Comment: @david thanks, I made notes in my book to correct these! Especially the first one is a bit dangerous. Maybe they didnt check the problems? Or otherwise, would you mind checking my calculations and see if you agree with my result or with the book solution?